# Is it possible to specify a global constant for a struct like a `time::Duration`?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to specify a global constant for a struct like a `time::Duration`?

```
const DELAY_TIME: time::Duration = ???
...
thread::sleep(DELAY_TIME);
```

Comment: I think because the fields of the `Duration` struct are private, you cannot use its constructor, and thus cannot use it as part of a `const` expression.

Comment: trying to use `Duration::new` yields this error: `error[E0015]: calls in constants are limited to struct and enum constructors`

Comment: The `new()` and `from_...()` functions for `Duration` became const around v1.32 of the compiler. So now you can do this, like:
`const DELAY_TIME: Duration = Duration::from_millis(250);`

Answer (score 0):

A `Duration` cannot be computed at compile-time, so you have two options:

- Store the parameters to the constructor (easy, since they are just  a `u64` and a `u32`)
- Store the `Duration` in a `lazy_static` (Requires dynamic allocation, atomic locking, and a dependent crate. Not recommended here).

Here's how to do the first option:

```
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread::sleep;

const DELAY_SECONDS: u64 = 1;
const DELAY_NANO_SECONDS: u32 = 0;

fn main() {
    sleep(Duration::new(DELAY_SECONDS, DELAY_NANO_SECONDS));
}
```